# Keeping `knitr` from popping up plot windows

Tags: r, knitr

I'm switching from `Sweave` to `knitr` and like it very much. Big THANKS to Yihui!

One thing that keeps annoying me is that plot windows pop up and get active. So when I write while `knitr` is working, my editor looses focus every so often. This happens even if there's no plot produced in the code chunk.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's my `sessionInfo ()`, in case that helps:

```
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] hyperSpec.sim_0.5       mvtnorm_0.9-9992        hyperSpec_0.98-20120531
[4] lattice_0.20-6          knitr_0.5              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] arrayhelpers_0.75-20120531 codetools_0.2-8           
 [3] digest_0.5.2               evaluate_0.4.2            
 [5] formatR_0.4                highlight_0.3.1           
 [7] parser_0.0-14              plyr_1.7.1                
 [9] Rcpp_0.9.10                stringr_0.6               
[11] tools_2.15.0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This must have been fixed in [a commit last week](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/99f5888244b068bfc817e83115f5ca35acd9781d). There will not be plot windows opened any more. If you do not know how to install the development version, you will wait for about one week for the next CRAN release, otherwise just [install from Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/#readme).

Comment: This is great.  I had a hack for this, but it was dangerous in various ways.

Comment: @BenBolker You mean you had a similar hack as mine and it was dangerous? (I temporarily changed the default device to `pdf(file=NULL)`)

Comment: I used `options(device = function(...) { .Call("R_GD_nullDevice", PACKAGE = "grDevices")` (this may have been at a time when `pdf(file=NULL)` was not working).  It had two big drawbacks: (1) if the `knitr` file ended prematurely, before I had a chance to reset the graphics device, things got confusing; (2) students who were working through the R code sometimes executed that command and got very confused thereafter.

Comment: You are right. I'm not sure if I was the guy who brought this hidden null device out (http://yihui.name/en/2010/12/a-special-graphics-device-in-r-the-null-device/), and I also realized the danger, so I wrote to Paul and he came up with the safer null device since R 2.14.1 (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/9). Now `knitr` uses this device by default; it is safe, and users will never see it (unless they read the source code of `knitr`).